# How can I refresh mDNSResponder.exe in Windows without -remove command

Tags: windows, refresh, zeroconf, mdns

I had an client application that made with mDNSResponder.exe. mDNSResponder carried out real-time updating data on client program received from state of some server hardwares such as DVR or ip-camera in certain closed network environment.

I just tried to make a new method that client updates state received from server hardwares using mDNSResponder.exe after updating state from client with another communication protocol such as TCP. But I has encountered a problem that mDNSResponder.exe failed to update reflected state made from process with another communication protocol. As I see, mDNSResponder.exe stored some received states in intervals between updating timing and show up the previous state, not current state.

The '-remove' and '-install' command doesn't be helped in this case because other application also uses mDNSResponder.exe. This action will hurt other application.

So in Windows OS (XP, 7, 8), I want to find reset (or refresh) mDNSResponder.exe without -remove command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, whether I understood your usecase, for me, it looks like that your application does not provide correct mDNS messages.

As far as you like to control (reset) the mDNSResopnder Cache(!) at development time, Apple gave these hints: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1310/_index.html.

In order to check, whether your application correctly manages Bonjour messages, I recommend to use the small Apple Tool 'dns-sd.exe', which is able to simulate Bonjour application behaviour (e.g. register or query for mDNS/DNS-SD services/instance/domains). It is part of the Apple SDK for Windows:
https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/index.html